# XSLT - Is there a way to append to attributes added with <xsl:attribute>?

Tags: xml, xslt

Simplified example:

```
<xsl:template name="helper">
  <xsl:attribute name="myattr">first calculated value</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/>
  <myelem>
    <xsl:call-template name="helper" />
    <xsl:attribute name="myattr">second calculated value</xsl:attribute>
  </myelem>
</xsl:template>
```

Is there some way for the second  to *append* the second calculated value to the same `myattr` attribute in the result node?

I've seen it is possible to use an attribute value template if the target attribute is in the source xml, but can I reference somehow the value of the attribute I have earlier appended to the result node?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach you could take is add a parameter to your helper template, which you append to the attribute value.

```
<xsl:template name="helper">
  <xsl:param name="extra" />
  <xsl:attribute name="myattr">first calculated value<xsl:value-of select="$extra" /></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Then you can just past in your second calculate value as the parameter

```
<xsl:template match="/>
  <myelem>
    <xsl:call-template name="helper">
      <xsl:with-param name="extra">second calculated value</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </myelem>
</xsl:template>
```

You don't have to set the param with each call though. If you don't want anything appended, just called the **helper** template with no parameter, and won't append anything to the first calculated value.

Comment: Great idea! One further question though: can I add more parameters to the `helper` template, and potentially use more `<xsl:with-param>` elements in the call?

Comment: (Answering my own question:) Yes, one can use more parameters.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest approach would be to change the nesting a bit - have the `helper` just generate text nodes and put the `<xsl:attribute>` in the calling template:

```
<xsl:template name="helper">
  <xsl:text>first calculated value</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/>
  <myelem>
    <xsl:attribute name="myattr">
      <xsl:call-template name="helper" />
      <xsl:text>second calculated value</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </myelem>
</xsl:template>
```

This will set `myattr` to "first calculated valuesecond calculated value" - if you want a space between "value" and "second" you must include that inside one of the `<xsl:text>` elements

```
      <xsl:text> second calculated value</xsl:text>
```

Comment: That's a good answer, although in the real case the `helper` template adds many more attributes, and in the `<myelem>` node may or may not modify `myattr` according to certain calculations. So, nice idea but not convenient in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  <xsl:template name="helper">
    <xsl:attribute name="myattr">first calculated value</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <myelem>
      <xsl:call-template name="helper" />
      <xsl:variable name="temp" select="@myattr"/>
      <xsl:attribute name="myattr">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($temp, 'second calculated value')"  />
      </xsl:attribute>
    </myelem>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: That won't work - the `select="@myattr"` will look in the context node of the input tree, not the output tree.  In this case that node is the document root node (`/`) which can never have any attributes.

Answer (score 0):

While it's more or less the same thing, I'd prefer the more concise way of creating a variable as opposed to having a helper template. Note that you can still call a template from within xsl:variable for the more complicated case.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <myelem>
    <xsl:variable name="first">first calculated value </xsl:variable >
    <xsl:attribute name="myattr">
       <xsl:value-of select="concat($first, 'second calculated value')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </myelem>
</xsl:template>
```